# Different TD widths within same width TR

Tags: css, html, dom, html-table

I have a table I want to modify. There are two rows and two columns on each row.
So the first row has two cells where the first cell has 70% of the width and the second cell has 30% of the parent table.. The second row has two cells where the first cell has 60% of the width and the second cell has 40% of the parent table. Even though i explicitly state the widths, why does the second row absorb the characteristics of the first row?

Here is the code. Why does it not work the way I want it to?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="border:1px black;width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:70%">January</td>
    <td style="width:30%">$100</td>
  </tr>
    <td style="width:60%">feb</td>
    <td style="width:40%">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All cells in a column will always display with the same width

Comment: That's simply how table cells work. Columns in the same row have the same width.

Comment: You should just split it into two tables. http://jsfiddle.net/6BCBy/ Although, I can't think of any reason why you'd want to do this.

Comment: yeah simple solution^

Comment: thanks guys...just wanted to know why it was happening and if it was possible thats all

Answer (score 1):

For First Column `(<td width="70%">)` you have set width=70% and in second row first column you have set column width=60%.

**Note** : in table highest column width automatically apply for same column. in your case first column of table is 70% for both rows even if you have use 60% for second row first column.